# is there a way to override firegento-magesetup2/Plugin/Catalog/ListProductPlugin.php

Tags: magento2, module, overrides, file

I just updated to latest magento2 but I have a Fatal Error which is related to this merge request https://github.com/firegento/firegento-magesetup2/pull/39/files and I would like to override without to make the changes in vendor. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. First create a new directory `app/coda/local/FireGento/MageSetup`, `FireGento/MageSetup` is the module name is called `FireGento_MageSetup` (you can see it [here](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-magesetup2/blob/develop/registration.php)).

Then you need to actually override the file, you do this by copying `Plugin/Catalog/ListProductPlugin.php` to the directory you just created, make sure you keep the same directory and this should work. You don't need to do anything else.

This should be straight forward.